# Magento State/Province Option Dropdown for United Kingdom like USA or Germany

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I need to show State and Province name of united Kingdom in Dropdown and like USA and Germany at registration time or shipping address in Magento. When Someone will select country United Kingdom then all State/Province should be Come as dropdown. 
Please help to get it out.[image]

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the default magento is that there are no default states / provinces for UK in the database that is why it is showing you the fallback display of a blank textbox instead of a dropdown list. To add them you must either input them by hand, OR you could follow this tutorial:

http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2011/04/adding-new-regionsstates-to-your-magento-installation-2/

Answer (score 0):

I prepared an excel file in which are listed all English and Italian Provinces.
Inside the file all the instruction to fill Magento Table (basic knowledge is required)
Please download file from

http://www.magentostoremanager.it/var/csv/directory_country_region.zip

You can also add new provinces and post here new location of the file.

In this way we will have very soon the whole list of provinces